# Disabling a script from another script

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script that is attached to many game objects. The script simply makes objects drag-able. I want this script to be disabled until a button is pressed.

I have used the below code to successfully find one of the game objects that the code is attached to:

```
    public class pressLoadBtn : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("LOAD BTN PRESSED");


        GameObject HB3 = GameObject.Find("HeavyBall3");
        draggableObject DraggableObject = HB3.GetComponent<draggableObject>();
        DraggableObject.enabled = false;
        Debug.Log("draggableObject script enabled is : " + DraggableObject.enabled);
    }
}
```

The console says that this script has been disabled but I know it has not been disabled. If the script had been disabled then I would not be able to drag the game object called 'HeavyBall3', but I can drag it.

Any ideas? I've tried shouting at the screen but that hasn't worked (yet).

Comment: Post the code of `draggableObject` please.

Comment: `draggableObject DraggableObject` isn't valid code. Or it shouldn't be, because class names should start with Upper case letters and variable names in lower case. `GameObject` vs. `gameObject`. Also, this appears to be C#, not UnityScript.

Comment: `The console says that this script has been disabled but I know it has not been disabled.` I would guess you don't know that, since the output tells you differently. Apparently it has been disabled, so the error is probably something else. Impossible to tell without seeing your code of `draggableObject`.

Comment: I realise that I have not followed C# conventions but surely that lone won't cause this issue?
The code for draggableObject is:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D))]

public class draggableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform ball;
    public Rigidbody2D r;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        r.velocity = (pos - ball.position) * 12;
    }
}

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D))]

public class draggableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform ball;
    public Rigidbody2D r;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        r.velocity = (pos - ball.position) * 12;
    }
}`

Comment: If I change the code to this:

`public class pressLoadBtn : MonoBehaviour {

void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("LOAD BTN PRESSED");


    GameObject HB3 = GameObject.Find("HeavyBall3");
    draggableObject DraggableObject = HB3.GetComponent<draggableObject>();
    Destroy(DraggableObject);
}
}`

Then it does indeed destroy the draggableObject script that is attached to the HeavyBall3 game object. So it is as if '.enabled = false;' just isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

For the love of pancakes! I solved it...

It turns out that '.enabled' only affects the calling of Start, Update, FixedUpdate and OnGUI (I got that info from Bunny83 on this thread:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/694778/cant-uncrosscross-a-script-component.html

It means I can't use 'OnMouseDrag' in my draggableObject.cs to drag objects but atleast I can move on with my life now!
3 days wasted! 3 days! Do you know what I could have done with 3 days? I could have built a model ship in a bottle! I could have cleaned the gutters. I could have fixed the lawnmower. But no, I found out that '.enabled' isn't all it's cracked up to be.

And just so you know, draggableObject.cs code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D))]

public class draggableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform ball;
    public Rigidbody2D r;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        r.velocity = (pos - ball.position) * 12;
    }
}
```